# No response from Docker container during load test

Tags: docker, jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to execute load testing on my architecture using Docker containers.

The architecture I designed:

```
+---------------+       +---------------+       +--------------+
| Docker Apache |------>| Docker Tomcat |------>| Docker MySQL |
+---------------+       +---------------+       +--------------+
```

I use JMeter to validate this architecture, but when I launch just 100 requests in the same time, I received around 80% "Socket closed" errors. But Apache logs reveals no errors.

If I changed the architecture to use a classic Apache instead of Docker, I'm not experiencing these errors (all requests are successfully handled by Apache), but I have now 408 HTTP errors between Apache and Docker Tomcat.

```
+---------------+       +---------------+       +--------------+
|    Apache     |------>| Docker Tomcat |------>| Docker MySQL |
+---------------+       +---------------+       +--------------+
```

I think docker-proxy has problems to handle a lot of simultaneous connections, but is there a way to tune it to resolve this issue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you attach your containers shared ports and describe how you run containers?

Comment: Hi. If you have found a fix please share it with other users who might stumble into the same issue :)